# What is the reason that 'string' index was not found on HTMLElement type?

Tags: typescript, dom-events

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("input-dialog") as HTMLDialogElement;

const someFunction = () => {
  const key = "showModal";
  dialog[key]();
  //No error occurred

  const key: string = "showModal"
  dialog[key]()
  // Error No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on types
  ...
}
```

While studying typescript, an error occurred that the string could not be used as an index.
Why can any type be used as an index and string is not possible?
What is wrong? and How to fix it? I'd appreciate your help.

I tried to handle the DOM element with typescript but I face a problem. I really want to know What is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that in your example, the first declaration of `key` isn't actually a string. The type of `key` is `showModal`. This is a TypeScript oddity. It sees that you're using `key` to index an `HTMLDialogElement` so it constrains the type to only valid strings for indexing an `HTMLDialogElement`. I.e, one of the names of the properties that exist on such an object.

```
const dialog = document.getElementById("input-dialog") as HTMLDialogElement;

const foo = () => {
  const key = "showModal";
  // type of key is "showModal"
  dialog[key](); // works
}

const bar = () => {
  const key: string = "showModal";
  // type of key is string
  dialog[key]; // doesn't work
}

const foz = (key: string) => {
  // type of key is string
  dialog[key]; // doesn't work
}

const baz = (key: "showModal" | "show") => {
  dialog[key]; // works
}
```

Comment: Oh... I understand what I did wrong. I needed to be more specific about the type I would use. Thank you for answering my question!